# 4 Errors when trying to use T4 template (View)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, nuget, t4

I am taking a look into T4 and scaffolding and I decided to give it a try. So I got the [MvcScaffolding](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MvcScaffolding) package on NuGet in order to customize a "Create" template in a test project.

After I have done very small changes (added css styles and translated the button texts) I decided to test my template by generating a View with my own "Create" scaffolding template.

Then I got the error bellow. I have checked the references on my project and everything seems there. Any ideas on how to fix this?

**EDIT:** I have just realized that some of my VS2010 AddOns were generating this error. Once disabled, it worked but my template wasn't used...

[image: T4 error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same error and was able to solve it by directly pointing to the referenced libaries in my View template:

```
<#@ assembly name="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.Entity.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.Linq.dll" #>
```

The source of this issue was an extension installed -> **tangible T4 Editor**. After deinstalling my T4 templates started to work without complete paths.

Comment: I removed the tangible T4 Editor and that helped. Thank you!